# Getting 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'arrayify')' while signing safeTransaction with ethAdapter

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis, safe-core-sdk

I am getting the following error while signing a simple ether transfer transaction with the Safe Core SDK.

```js
const ethAdapter = new EthersAdapter({
  ethers: ether3,
  signer: ether3.getSigner(0),
})
const safeSdk = await Safe.create({ ethAdapter, safeAddress })
let transaction = {
  to: 'receiver_address',
  data: '0x',
  value: '1000000000000000000',
}
transaction.nonce = await safeService.getNextNonce(safeAddress)
const safeTransaction = await safeSdk.createTransaction(transaction)
await safeSdk.signTransaction(safeTransaction) // this is throwing error
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'arrayify')
    at EthersAdapter.signMessage (EthersAdapter.js?298f:103:1)
    at generateSignature (index.js?1e12:55:1)
    at async Safe.signTransaction (Safe.js?3512:258:1)
```

Not able to understand why it is happening because previously I was using web3Adapter and that was not giving any such error.

**Edit(25 Jan 2022):**

```js
import { ethers } from 'ethers'

const ether3 = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum) // I am using different provider but it is similar to metamask
const ethAdapter = new EthersAdapter({
  ethers: ether3,
  signer: ether3.getSigner(0),
})
const safeSdk = await Safe.create({ ethAdapter, safeAddress })
let transaction = {
  to: 'receiver_address',
  data: '0x',
  value: '1000000000000000000',
}
transaction.nonce = await safeService.getNextNonce(safeAddress)
const safeTransaction = await safeSdk.createTransaction(transaction)
await safeSdk.signTransaction(safeTransaction) // this is throwing error
```

`signMessage` method from the EthersAdapter class:

```js
signMessage(message) {
  const messageArray = __classPrivateFieldGet(this, _EthersAdapter_ethers, "f").utils.arrayify(message);
  return __classPrivateFieldGet(this, _EthersAdapter_signer, "f").signMessage(messageArray);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is thrown in the method `signMessage` from the `EthersAdapter` class:

```js
signMessage(message: string): Promise<string> {
  const messageArray = this.#ethers.utils.arrayify(message)
  return this.#signer.signMessage(messageArray)
}
```

where `this.#ethers.utils` seems to be undefined.

Please, make sure that your object `ether3` is valid, it should be imported like this:

```js
import { ethers } from "ethers"
```

Comment: I checked again all imports are fine. let me update the post to show how I initialized the `ether3`. Also in my case it is
`
signMessage(message) {
  const messageArray = __classPrivateFieldGet(this, _EthersAdapter_ethers, "f").utils.arrayify(message);
        return __classPrivateFieldGet(this, _EthersAdapter_signer, "f").signMessage(messageArray);
    }`

Comment: the issue is resolved. The problem was with the initialization of the 'ethAdapter'.
It should be like this:


```
const ethAdapter = new EthersAdapter({
  ethers,
  signer: ether3.getSigner(0),
})
```
and not


```
const ethAdapter = new EthersAdapter({
  ethers: ether3,
  signer: ether3.getSigner(0),
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is raised because `0x` is not valid "arrayify" according to ethers.

https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/3de1b815014b10d223a42e524fe9c25f9087293b/packages/bytes/src.ts/index.ts#L92

Change

```
let transaction = {
  to: 'receiver_address',
  data: '0x',
  value: '1000000000000000000',
}
```

to

```
let transaction = {
  to: 'receiver_address',
  data: '0x00',
  value: '1000000000000000000',
}
```